# is there a way to alter translate.csv for ADMIN without altering core file?

Tags: admin, localisation

The file I am looking at is `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/locale/en_US/translate.csv`

I would like to change translations in the admin back-end without editing this file (in case there is an update that overwrites it in the future

Is there a method to create a separate translate.csv file that will be checked in priority for back-end changes like there is for the front-end?

Comment: You can enable the inline translation in backend and translate the content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is common practice to create an admin theme for such modifications:

1. Create the directory `app/design/adminhtml/default/yourname`
2. Activate the theme in any custom `config.xml`:

   ```
   <config>
       <stores>
           <admin>
               <design>
                   <theme>
                       <default>yourname</default>
                   </theme>
               </design>
           </admin>
       </stores>
   </config>
   ```
3. For translations, then copy `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/locale/en_US/translate.csv` to `app/design/adminhtml/default/yourname/locale/en_US/translate.csv` and make your changes.