# How to move Admin notification block to header?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, layout, blocks, template

I would like to move the notification toolbar thats located under the menu of Magento's admin panel and place it in a div i have in the header.

I tried achieving this by cutting the following line from `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('notifications'); ?>
```

and pasting it in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/header.phtml`

but that didn't work.

could someone advise me on how to move the notification block to the header section, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not edit core files. Instead create a custom admin theme as described here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/80533/243

Then copy the modified `header.phtml` to `app/design/adminhtml/default/yourname/template/page/header.phtml`

And create `app/design/adminhtml/default/yourname/layout/local.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="unsetChild"><block>notifications</block></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="header">
            <action method="append"><block>notifications</block></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

This will remove the notifications block from its current position in the layout hierarchy (as child of `root`) and add it as as child of `header` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to edit your xml. To call any `childHtml` in `header.phtml`, you must have that block defined inside of your `header` block section in corresponding xml file.

Open your `main.xml` and find

```
<block type="adminhtml/page_header" name="header" as="header"></block>
```

and replace it with:

```
        <block type="adminhtml/page_header" name="header" as="header">
            <block type="index/adminhtml_notifications" name="index_notifications" template="index/notifications.phtml"></block>
        </block>
```

After this you may call `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('index_notifications');?>` in your `header.phtml` file.

Remember you shouldn't edit the core files. Instead you should extend the file.

Hope this will do the trick.

Comment: sorry, but this method didn't seem to work for me!