# Updating Copyright / making private on Admin login

Tags: admin, login, copyright

I know how to change the copyright info on a customer view, but how do I get rid of the magento copyright on the admin login box?

I'm working on a multi-vendor store and want no reference to Magento (mainly for security purposes).

Answer (score 0):

Your admin login should not be visible to others in the first place. It has become best practice to set up a different admin URL in the store configuration. You could also protect the admin URL additionally with basic authentication (`htaccess` password).

You also want to delete or protect the `/downloader` directory.

Regarding "want no reference to Magento": If you don't want anybody to recognize that it's a Magento site, it's going to be more work. See: [Protect a site from wappalyzer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104889/protect-a-site-from-wappalyzer/104894#104894)

**Update:** I overlooked the "multi-vendor-store" bit, so there's more to it. You would need to create a custom admin theme (as described in [is there a way to alter translate.csv for ADMIN without altering core file?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62374/is-there-a-way-to-alter-translate-csv-for-admin-without-altering-core-file/80533#80533)) where you can remove the footer, change the logo and so on. For just a modified login screen, this little extension comes in handy: https://github.com/SchumacherFM/Magento-OptimizedBackendLogin/

Comment: Thanks - I did change the logos without a problem, that was easy :) I'll look at the other suggestions, thanks.