# Change the name of a tab in admin Product Information

Tags: admin, adminhtml, localisation, admin-panel, language

I'd like to change the name of of the tab "Related Products" in the Product Information in the Administration area (/catalog_product/edit/id/123).

I could easily do it changing the name in the code (app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php) but I'd prefer to avoid changing the Magento core.
So I was looking at the language files (app/locale/en_GB and app/locale/en_US), but the has no effect.

Any idea?

I verified the language used in the admin area is English UK (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14159348/1190011).

(Magento CE 1.9)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the line

```
"Related Products","Related Products"
```

in `app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv` *should* work, but since you don't want to edit core files, let's not waste time on that. Instead, create your own admin theme where you can define custom translations.

This is explained here: [is there a way to alter translate.csv for ADMIN without altering core file?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62374/is-there-a-way-to-alter-translate-csv-for-admin-without-altering-core-file/80533#80533)

Then you'll add the following in `en_US/translate.csv` (or `en_GB/translate.csv`):

```
"Mage_Catalog::Related Products","Your custom translation here"
```

Comment: Hi @fschmengler I didn't really get the second point in the answer in the link. In which `config.xml` should I activate the theme?

Comment: In any custom module. If you already have a module for general project configuration or theme, use that. If not, create one.